# Add users using useradd with a textfile

Tags: linux, bash

I want to create some users using a file text in which there are informations about the users. The file text is written like that :

```
#FIRSTNAME LASTNAME UID
firstname1 lastname1 uid1
firstname2 lastname2 uid2
etc ...
```

This is what I tried to do for now :

```
#!/bin/bash
while read var1 var2 var3
do
 sudo useradd $var1$var2 -u $var3
done < ~/Users.txt
```

But I have to find a way to ignore the first line... I don't know where to add `grep -v "#"` in my script...

(I'm trying to find the easiest way to do it)

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this:

```
while read line
do
     # do process
     sudo useradd "$var1$var2" -u "$var3"
done < <(grep -v '^#' file)
```

It is always recommended to quote the variables.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
while read var1 var2 var3
do
   if [[ ! $var1 =~ "#"* ]]
   then
       sudo useradd $var1$var2 -u $var3
   fi
done < ~/names
```

Comment: `[[ $var1 != "#"* ]]` is better check

Comment: Yo don't need to use `=~` that is for regex. Use `!=` as I suggested